# How to get WebDriver Instance(Object) from Hooks(@Before) for parallel executions of scenarios

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, cucumber

I want to get WebDriver Instance(Object) from the Hooks Class in @Before Annotation setup() method.
And I want to do it in such a way that I am able to run my scenarios in parallel.

I know what are Hooks and @Before annotation in cucumber but I am not able to understand how do I start my browser and pass that instance to the step definition class.

I have created a sample project to highlight the issue.
I have a feature file with 2 scenarios. Those two scenario are go to *Bing* and *Google* search pages and verifying the page titles respectively.

Below is my Sample code and project structure:

**Project structure:**

[image]

**PageTitleVerification.feature**

```
Feature: Verify the title of the search pages

  @regression
  Scenario: Validate the Bing Home Page title
    Given Go to Bing Home Page
    Then  Verify Bing page title
    
    
  @regression
  Scenario: Validate the Google Home Page title
    Given Go to Google Home Page
    Then  Verify Google page title
```

**BingHomePage.java**

```
public class BingHomePage {
    WebDriver driver;
    
    public BingHomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    
    public void gotoBingHomePage() {
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.bing.com/");
    }
    
    public boolean verifyBingPageTitle() {
        String expectedPageTitle = "Bing";
        String actualPageTitle = driver.getTitle();
        
        return actualPageTitle.equals(expectedPageTitle);
    }
    
}
```

**GoogleHomePage.java**

```
public class GoogleHomePage {

    WebDriver driver;

    public GoogleHomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void gotoGoogleHomePage() {
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");
    }

    public boolean verifyGooglePageTitle() {
        String expectedPageTitle = "Google";
        String actualPageTitle = driver.getTitle();
        
        return actualPageTitle.equals(expectedPageTitle);
    }

}
```

**BingStepDef.java**

```
public class BingStepDef implements En {

    //Question: 
    //How do I initialize this driver instance with the Hooks @Before
    WebDriver driver ;

    BingHomePage bingHomePage;

    public BingStepDef() {

        bingHomePage = new BingHomePage(driver);
        
        Given("Go to Bing Home Page", () -> {
            bingHomePage.gotoBingHomePage();
        });

        Then("Verify Bing page title", () -> {
            boolean result = bingHomePage.verifyBingPageTitle();
            Assert.assertTrue(result);
        });

    }

}
```

**GoogleStepDef.java**

```
public class GoogleStepDef implements En {

    //Question: 
    //How do I initialize this driver instance with the Hooks @Before
    WebDriver driver ;
    
    GoogleHomePage googleHomePage;
    
    public GoogleStepDef() {
        
        googleHomePage = new GoogleHomePage(driver);

        Given("Go to Google Home Page", () -> {
            googleHomePage.gotoGoogleHomePage();
        });

        Then("Verify Google page title", () -> {
            boolean result = googleHomePage.verifyGooglePageTitle();
            Assert.assertTrue(result);
        });
    
    }

}
```

**Hooks.java**

```
public class Hooks {

    WebDriver driver;
    
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./src/main/resources/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
    
}
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/main/java/com/alok/feature/"
        , glue = {"com.alok.stepdef"}
        , plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber"}
        , dryRun = false
        , monochrome = true
        , tags = {"@regression"}
)
public class TestRunner {
    
}
```

**TestRunnerParallel.java**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "./src/main/java/com/alok/feature"
        , glue = {"com.alok.stepdef"}
        , plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber"}
        , dryRun = false
        , monochrome = true
        , tags = {"@regression"}
)

public class TestRunnerParallel extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true) 
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }

}
```

**TestNG.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" data-provider-thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test Regression" >
         <classes>
             <class name="com.alok.test.TestRunnerParallel"/>
          </classes>
     </test> 
</suite>
```

Comment: Sorry for opptopic. Why are you using `PageFactory.init`? You do not have fields in your page objects except of a driver field. So there is nothing to initialize in your objects.

Comment: You are correct,Alexey. This just a sample project I created to put my question across. kindly ignore `PageFactory.init`. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to run your current configuration in parallel? As far as I can see you create a new instance of webdriver in @Before. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: No, Alexey. I am not able to pass that instance to the StepDef  Classes viz: BingStepDef , GoogleStepDef

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use hooks to supply WebDriver to your scenarios. Instead use PicoContainer dependency injection framework.

1. Mark the fields of your step class with `@Inject` annotations
2. Create a class that would implement `WebDriver` interface and delegate calls to internal driver object that would be lazily initialized. That class should also implement `Disposable` interface where you kill your internal driver object.
3. Create custom object factory that would delegate calls to `PicoFactory`. In the constructor of your custom factory add classes that should be injected according to your steps logic
4. Register your factory as [SPI service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html).
5. Set `cucumber.object-factory` property in `cucumber.properties` file pointing to your custom factory

This should be enough. Here is more detailed tutorial of [making your cucmber-java8 work with PicoContainer](https://webelement.click/en/cucumber_java_8_selenium_pageobject_picocontainer_tutorial).

Comment: Thanks Alexey. The solutions that have provided in the links are using Cucumber prior to the Lambda expressions. I am using Cuccumber-Java8(as mentioned in question) its not working for it.

Comment: I believe they have to work in your cucumber as well. It is just a concept that does not rely on Java version.

Comment: I meant Alexey was that in new Cucumber Step Def class we have to implement En interface (`io.cucumber.java8.En`) i.e `public class GoogleStepDef implements En {` and we define the steps  inside a constructor (with no arguments) unlike earlier we used the _`@Given`_ annotation. `public GoogleStepDef() {` and `Given("Go to Google Home Page", () -> { //.... });` Refer the _GoogleStepDef_ class shown in the question.
Since Pico forces us to define a constructor with arguments and in the new Cucumber Step Def we have to define the constructor **without** argument this is where I am getting stuck.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks Alexey. Will try it and let you know. might take a couple of days to revert. :-)

Comment: Hi Alexey. I went through the example from the link that you mentioned in the answer. 
But I found a better way to Inject the dependency. I used Spring Boot the share the dependencies. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Spring is just another one DI container like PicoContainer. More powerful of course. Spring boot is a framework to write backend for web apps. So using it for only managing injection is a bit overwhelming I believe. But if it works for you why not.